# RaphaelJs and RequireJs Not Working Togther

Tags: raphael, requirejs

I am trying to load Raphaeljs using Requirejs. I tried this solution here:
https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/pull/540

but when I load it I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined

I looking more into it I saw that eve is undefined. Anyone have any ideas to get this to work with requirejs?

Answer (score 7):

You can clone Raphael and update the submodules as Dmitry describes [here](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/#quickstart-guide), then for RequireJS, do this:

```
paths: {
  "eve": "libs/raphael/eve/eve",
  "raphael": "libs/raphael/raphael"
},
shim: {
  'eve': {
    exports: "eve"
  },
  'raphael': {
    deps: ["eve"],
    exports: "Raphael"
  }
}
```

The just use `"raphael"` as a dependency when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem few weeks ago, but I was using [JamJS](http://jamjs.org/), which is a front end package manager that **uses Require.JS** and manages *require.config.js* for you.

This might not solve your problem since I used JamJS, but for whatever is worth here's how I solved it: I created a package for RaphaelJS - using [pmcelhaney's fork](https://github.com/pmcelhaney/raphael/tree/pure-amd-2) and also for [Eve](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/eve). You can get the packages from

- Eve http://jamjs.org/packages/#/details/eve
- Raphael http://jamjs.org/packages/#/details/raphael-amd